# Ajax & PHP uploading files

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, upload

I'm starting with web programming with javascript and i have a little problem with uploading file.

I find this: http://tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-form/
but I have no idea how to use upload.php file in mvc project. What to use as an action of form and where should be plasted this php code?

Can anyone give mi some hints?

Comment: You don't use the PHP verbatim. You rewrite it to fit whatever the conventions of your MVC framework are.

Comment: You have to change form action path to you upload file path route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can upload you're file with ajax if you create a controller with php:

```
<?php
    $valid_exts = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'); // Autorized extensions
    $max_size = 200 * 1024; // Max file size
    $path = 'uploads/'; // Folder where to upload
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') 
    {
        if( ! empty($_FILES['image']) ) 
        {
            // Get the extension of the file
            $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            // Test the file format if it's allowed
            if (in_array($ext, $valid_exts) AND $_FILES['image']['size'] < $max_size) 
            {
                $path = $path . uniqid(). '.' .$ext;
                // Put the file in the folder of uploads
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $path))
                    echo $path; // returning the path
                else
                    echo 'uploads/err.gif'; // returning the error message or path or whatever
            } 
            else 
                echo 'uploads/err.gif';
        } 
        else
            echo 'uploads/err.gif';
    } 
    else
        echo 'uploads/err.gif';
?>
```

In you're view, you have to include jQuery.form library and. you create a form, and inside the form you put an image and a button, the form should have the link of you're php file as action, and call this function:

```
$('#form').ajaxUpload($('#button'),$('#image_preview'));
```

The definition of `ajaxUpload` function is this:

```
jQuery.fn.ajaxUpload = function(Button,Preview)
{
    var Frm = $(this); // form
    var Btn = Button; // upload button
    var Prev = Preview; // preview area 
    Btn.click(function()
    {
        // implement with ajaxForm Plugin
        Frm.ajaxForm(
        {
            beforeSend: function()
            {
                Btn.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                Prev.fadeOut();
            },
            success: function(Result)
            {
                Frm.resetForm();
                Btn.removeAttr('disabled');
                Prev.attr("src",Result).fadeIn();
            },
            error: function(Result)
            {
                Btn.removeAttr('disabled');
                Prev.attr("src",Result).fadeIn();
            }
        });
    });
};
```